# How can I change the width/height of a div without changing position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to [duplicate what this guy did](http://thuongvuho.com/circletime/) but without using canvas. I want to have a div in the center of my page and simply increment the width/height/border-radius by 10px every second. This works pretty well, but for some reason the bigger the div gets the more it moves to the lower right. The circle is not staying still, its center positioning is changing as it gets larger. How can I change the width/height of a div without changing position?

**main.css**

```
div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  margin-top:-50px; /* this is half the height of your div*/  
  margin-left:-100px; /*this is half of width of your div*/
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
    <title>CircleTime</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css"></link>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.coffee**

```
incrementCircle = ->
  newSize = circle.height() + 10
  circle.height newSize
  circle.width newSize
  circle.css 'border-radius', newSize

$(document).ready ->
  window.circle = $("div")
  setInterval(incrementCircle, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your coffeescript, keep updating the margins like this:

```
incrementCircle = ->
newSize = circle.height() + 10
circle.height newSize
circle.width newSize
circle.css 'border-radius', newSize
circle.css 'margin-top', newSize/-2
circle.css 'margin-left', newSize/-2

$(document).ready ->
  window.circle = $("div")
  setInterval(incrementCircle, 1000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sw0zn36e/5/

Comment: This works, but on the first iteration the circle "jumps" to the right. After that it remains static, which is good. In any case, thanks!

Comment: Nm, fixed it on my own. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Are you also changing the margins?

```
margin-top:-50px; /* this is half the height of your div*/    
margin-left:-100px; /*this is half of width of your div*/
```

Just add this to your `incrementCircle`

```
circle.css 'margin', -(newSize/2) + 'px, 0px, 0px, ' + -(newSize/2) + 'px'
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be a css problem.

Try this:

```
div {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switching to `margin: 0 auto;` works. See this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myWBZW

Comment: This appears to animate the circle from it's *top center* rather than the *center center*.

Comment: It was to show that ```margin: 0 auto;``` works to keep it in place, not to be an end all solution. The OP specifies the top margin explicitly, so that margin can be applied again, and it'll be centered.

Comment: You should include that in your answer as well, otherwise you are providing a half answer.

Comment: ```margin: 0 auto;``` is what is needed here. The codepen was just to be somewhat helpful. The other css solution doesn't center vertically either. Why did you decide to jump on this question and just pick at my answer?